# How to get emacs to ignore the shebang (#!/some/interpreter) when determining what mode to open a file

Tags: python, emacs, jython

I'm editing python files which are intended to be executed by Jython so they the appropriate shebang at the top of the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/jython
```

This results in the files being opened in jython-mode.  However, I want to use python-mode.  I can not seem to get the buffer into python-mode and out of jython-mode in anyway other than removing the shebang and reverting the buffer.  Even running *python-mode* doesn't accomplish this (the buffer is still in jython-mode).  Can I put some type of hook in place to ignore the shebang for .py files?

If it matters, I'm using emacs-22.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following to your `.emacs`:

```
(delq (assoc "jython" interpreter-mode-alist) interpreter-mode-alist)
```

See the documentation for [How Emacs Chooses a Major Mode](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Auto-Major-Mode.html).  Or you can use the heavy hammer and get rid of shebang handling altogether:

```
(setq interpreter-mode-alist nil)
```

Comment: Is that going to disable all modes from being set by the shebang?

Comment: @MarkRoddy Yup, I've updated to provide answer for just jython.

Comment: I added, to my `.emacs` file, the first line you suggested.  But, I still have exactly the same experience as the OP.  In my case, emacs23 appears to be forcing me into Jython mode on the basis of the presence of `import java.lang.Double as Double`.  If I comment out this one import, I can get into Python mode.